# Cannot load image from the Windows Pictures folder into Excel file using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba macro to add an image into the Excel file. The main code to add the file is this...

```
Dim s As Shape

Set s = Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(strFilename, msoFalse, msoCTrue, lngLeft, lngTop, -1, -1)

With s
    .Height = 60
    .Locked = True
End With
```

lngLeft and lngTop are coordinates set earlier in the code.
The target image file is selected using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)`

strFilename is filled using the following code...

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim objFile As Variant

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Choose a logo graphic ..."
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.png; *.jpeg", 1
    .FilterIndex = 2
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
    .Show

For Each objFile In .SelectedItems
    strFilename = Dir(objFile, vbNormal)
Next objFile
```

Problem: Everything works perfectly on my system and my colleagues and another random system. However, when our client, for whom it is meant, uses it, he cannot select an image from the Windows' Pictures folder. He can select it from any other folder though. He gets "Run-time error '1004': The specified file wasn't found."

All systems used in development, and testing are Windows 10 and the client is using Windows 7. Also, we are using the Office 2016 while he is using 2010.

Can anyone help with what could be the reason for this problem and a workaround?

Comment: Can you show me the code where strFilename is being declared and filled?

Comment: 'With fd
        .ButtonName = "Select"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Choose a logo graphic ..."
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.png; *.jpeg", 1
        .FilterIndex = 2
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
        .Show

        For Each objFile In .SelectedItems
            strFilename = Dir(objFile, vbNormal)
        Next objFile'

Comment: Ok, so the path is really dynamic... Would be great if you could try to debug this project on windows 7. Don't you have anyone with a Win7-computer or laptop? And another question: do they run the same version of office???

Comment: @Kathara, I didn't think this would make a difference if the Windows version was 7 or 10. Either way, we don't have any running on Win 7. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. I will check the client's Windows and Office versions.

Comment: Ok the windows version might not be the problem but the office version can certainly be. It would be better to check this as they change the vba functionality from version to version. This can create a lot of "bugs" when you want to take a 2010 version Workbook to Excel 2007 and so on.

Comment: Please add additional information or details to your question by way of an [edit] to the question itself, not in comments. It makes the information more readily available, and allows proper formatting of code. Thanks.

Comment: Why cant you use any of the free remote desktop services to see his end? It would probably be easier and faster to trouble shoot that way...

Comment: @KenWhite: I have edited the question to provide additional information. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @DougCoats This is the first time I have encountered such a problem, so frankly I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking for even if I do a remote desktop :) I am hoping someone on the community has faced this issue before

Comment: Updated with our and client's OS and Office versions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that seems to do the job. The problem was with this piece of code

```
For Each objFile In .SelectedItems
    strFilename = Dir(objFile, vbNormal)
Next objFile
```

When I added a messagebox, I found that strFilename has only file name (eg: myimage.jpg) without the full path. This doesn't seem to affect its functioning in Office 2016 on Windows 10. But for some reason, either Windows 7 or Office 2010 cannot work with it. So, I changed the way file path+file name string is generated to this and it works fine.

```
strFilename = .SelectedItems(1)
```